# Automatically shift window focus to "Find and Replace"

Tags: front-end, dialog-window

I'm running 11.1 on UbuntuMate.

Currently when I hit Ctl-F, the "Find and Replace" dialog window appears, but the active window remains the notebook I was in. I'd like to have Mathematica make the "Find and Replace" window the active window when invoked.

I've tried searching the Options Inspector, but I can't find the right setting.  Can someone please clue me in?

Comment: I run Mathematica (11.11.1) on OS X. For me what you asking for is the default behavior of Cmnd+F.  This suggests the your problem is peculiar to your operating system and not a Mathematica thing.

Comment: Yep, I'm finding similar differences in behavior between machines.  The challenge is to figure out what setting needs to be changed... oy. The joys of gnome.